# Eclipse plugin project "checkstyle internal error" says "cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate '...ForbidCertainImportsCheck'"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I haven't looked at my Eclipse plugin project for a few weeks, but after I updated to Neon.1, I  noticed the following error in the Problems view:

> Checkstyle execution failed due to an internal error. Please check the error log for details.

In the error log, I saw things like this:

> !MESSAGE Checkstyle-Plugin: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate
>   'com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.coding.ForbidCertainImportsCheck' class,
>   it is also not possible to instantiate it as com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.annotation.com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.coding.ForbidCertainImportsCheck,
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.blocks.com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.coding.ForbidCertainImportsCheck,
>   [deleted numerous similar class names],
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.coding.ForbidCertainImportsCheckCheck.
>   Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short
>   name usage http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Packages. Please also
>   recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.

After I saw this in my neon.1 workspace, I also noticed that my older workspace running in Mars.2 was also showing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to resolve this.

The parent POM of the project I work on had a change to its checkstyle configuration, and it now requires adding the "seventu" auxiliary checkstyle plugin, which I found at https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle .  Once I installed that (and did the usual "Maven Update Projects" invocation), the errors went away.